# Difficulty fitting gamma distribution with R

Tags: r

I am attempting to estimate parameters for a gamma distribution fit to ecological density (i.e. biomass per area) data. I have been using the fitdistr() command from the MASS package in R (version 3.0.0 : x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)). This is a maximum likelihood estimation command for distributional parameters.

The vectors of data are quite large, but summary statistics are as follows:

> Min. = 0;  1st Qu. = 87.67;  Median = 199.5;  Mean = 1255;  Variance =
>   2.79E+07;  3rd Qu. = 385.6;  Max. = 33880

The code I am using to run the MLE procedure is:

```
gdist <- fitdistr(data, dgamma, 
                  start=list(shape=1, scale=1/(mean(data))),lower=c(1,0.1))
```

R is giving me the following error:

> Error in optim(x = c(6.46791148085828, 4060.54750836902,
>   99.6201565968665,  :    non-finite finite-difference value [1]

Others who have experienced this type of issue and have turned to stackoverflow for help seem to have found the solution in adding the "lower=" argument to their code, and/or removing zeros. I find that R will provide parameters for a fit if I remove the zero observations, but I was under the impression that gamma distributions covered the range 0 <= x > inf (Forbes et al. 2011. Statistical Distributions)?

Have I gotten the wrong impression regarding the range of the gamma distribution? Or is there some other issue I am missing regarding MLE (in which I am a novice).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Getting a rough estimate by the method of moments (matching up the mean=shape*scale and variance=shape*scale^2) we have

```
mean <- 1255
var <- 2.79e7
shape = mean^2/var   ## 0.056
scale = var/mean     ## 22231
```

Now generate some data from this distribution:

```
set.seed(101)
x = rgamma(1e4,shape,scale=scale)
summary(x)
##     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
##     0.00      0.00      0.06   1258.00     98.26 110600.00 

MASS::fitdistr(x,"gamma")  ## error
```

I strongly suspect that the problem is that the underlying `optim` call assumes the parameters (shape and scale, or shape and rate) are of approximately the same magnitude, which they're not.  You can get around this by scaling your data:

```
(m <- MASS::fitdistr(x/2e4,"gamma"))  ## works fine
##      shape           rate    
##  0.0570282411   0.9067274280 
## (0.0005855527) (0.0390939393)
```

`fitdistr` gives a rate parameter rather than a scale parameter: to get back to the shape parameter you want, invert and re-scale ...

```
1/coef(m)["rate"]*2e4  ## 22057
```

By the way, the fact that the quantiles of the simulated data don't match your data very well (e.g. median of `x`=0.06 vs a median of 199 in your data) suggest that your data might not fit a Gamma all that well -- e.g. there might be some outliers affecting the mean and variance more than the quantiles?

PS above I used the built-in 'gamma' estimator in `fitdistr` rather than using `dgamma`: with starting values based on the method of moments, and scaling the data by 2e4, this works (although it gives a warning about `NaNs produced` unless we specify `lower`)

```
 m2 <- MASS::fitdistr(x/2e4,dgamma,
        start=list(shape=0.05,scale=1), lower=c(0.01,0.01))
```

Comment: +1 I'd be suspicious of any shape parameter < 1. True, the gamma distribution does allow for that, but IME such a value, especially together with a massive scale, means the data is probably too heavy-tailed for a gamma. Something like a generalised Pareto or extreme-value distribution might be a better fit.